# Sitemap is not indexed by google

Tags: xml, https, sitemap

I've added the sitemap using sitemaps.org protocol guide for a website which has only 1 page. Google webmaster tools showed that the 1 linked being submitted is indexed immediately after refreshing the sitemap page (yesterday), today it shows that the sitemap has 1 link submitted but not indexed. The website has a SSL Cert, but the submitted link was http not https. I found no difference when submitting the sitemap for both. XML-sitemaps validation tool shows no errors. I wish to fix it

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessarily an issue in your case. When search engines learn about new pages via sitemaps, they don't necessarily index all the pages. Google may not like your page enough.

You can check about other possible reasons why your [page is not indexed](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/page-is-not-indexing-checklist.html) and learn more about [the indexing process](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/indexing-process-introduction.html) (these are posts I wrote myself).